# Why it runs twice when seed in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just put `puts "test"` in the seeds file , when I run `rake db:seed`, I saw there are 2 lines "test"

Comment: Can you post your `/db/seeds.rb` file?

Comment: just one line `puts "test"`, it displays twice

Comment: Are you sure you don't run `rake db:seed` two times?

Comment: I am sure there two lines to display, but run once , I think you can test it in your seeds , just minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this when I load tasks in my Rails code, for example

```
# config/initializers/rake_load_tasks.rb
# DO NOT USE THIS, IT WILL CAUSE rails db:seed TO RUN TWICE
require "rake"
Rails.application.load_tasks
```